# Create artisan commands for package Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, command, package, laravel-5

I am developing a package for Laravel 5, now I need to create some new artisan command for this package. I have read the following articles but still stuck

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan

Question: What I need to do is grouping some artisan commands of laravel 5 into a single command and then add this new command to my package can anyone help me through the steps I have to take?

Answer (score 0):

I could be writing a huge answer but this video is better then 100 words:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BviKET-QTEQ

Also the link for the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands