# Creating a new ServiceProvider / Facade as a package in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, laravel-5

## Introduction

I've never worked with a framework before (Zend, CakePHP, etc) and finally decided to sit down and learn one. I'm starting with Laravel because the code looks pretty and unlike some other frameworks I tried to install, the "Hello, World!" example worked on the first try.

## The Goal

For the time being, I want my app to do something very simple:

1. User submits a request in the form of: `GET /dist/lat,lng`
2. The app uses the remote IP address and MaxMind to determine `$latitude1` and `$longitude1`
3. This request path is parsed for `$latitude2` and `$longitude2`
4. Using these two positions, we calculate the distance between them. To do this I'm using [Rafael Fragoso's WorldDistance PHP class](https://github.com/rafaelfragosom/world_distance)

Since I plan to re-use this function in later projects, it didn't seem right to throw all of the code into the `/app` directory. The two reusable parts of the application were:

1. A service provider that connects to MaxMind and returns a latitude and longitude
2. A service provider that takes two points on a globe and returns the distance

If I build facades correctly then instead of my `routes.php` file being a mess of closures within closures, I can simply write:

```
Route::get('dist/{input}', function($input){
    $input = explode( "," , $input );

    return Distance::getDistance( GeoIP::getLocation(), $input );
});
```

## What I've tried

#### Initial Attempt

For the first service provider, I found [Daniel Stainback's Laravel 5 GeoIP service provider](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip). It didn't install as easily as it should have (I had to manually copy `geoip.php` to the `/config` directory, update `/config/app.php` by hand, and run `composer update` and `php artisan optimize`) however it worked: A request to `GET /test` returned all of my information.

For the second service provider, I started by trying to mimic the directory structure and file naming convention of the GeoIP service provider. I figured that if I had the same naming convention, the autoloader would be able to locate my class. So I created `/vendor/stevendesu/worlddistance/src/Stevendesu/WorldDistance\WorldDistanceServiceProvider.php`:

```
<?php namespace Stevendesu\WorldDistance;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class WorldDistanceServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = false;

    public function register()
    {
        // Register providers.
        $this->app['distance'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new WorldDistance();
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['distance'];
    }

}
```

I then added this to my `/config/app.php`:

```
        'Stevendesu\WorldDistance\WorldDistanceServiceProvider',
```

This fails with a fatal error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 150:
Class 'Stevendesu\WorldDistance\WorldDistanceServiceProvider' not found
```

#### Using WorkBench

Since this utterly failed I figured that there must be some other file dependency: maybe without composer.json or without a README it gives up. I don't know. So I started to look into package creation. Several Google searches for "create package laravel 5" proved fruitless. Either:

1. They were using Laravel 4.2, in which case the advice was "run php artisan workbench vendor/package --resources"

Or

2. They were using Laravel 5, in which case [the docs were completely useless](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages)

The official Laravel 5 docs give you plenty of sample code, saying things like:

> All you need to do is tell Laravel where the views for a given namespace are located. For example, if your package is named "courier", you might add the following to your service provider's boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'courier');
}
```

This makes the assumption that you **have a service provider to put a boot method in**

Nothing in the docs says how to create a service provider in such a way that it will actually be loaded by Laravel.

I also found [several](http://laravel.io/forum/01-13-2015-laravel-5-package-development) [different](http://kodeinfo.com/post/laravel-4-5-package-development) [resources](http://stagerightlabs.com/blog/laravel5-pacakge-development-setup) all of which assume you have a repository and you just want to include it in your app, or assume you have "workbench". Nothing about creating a new package entirely from scratch.

PHP Artisan did not even have a "workbench" command, and there was no "workbench.php" file in `/config`, so anything I found related to workbench was worthless. I started doing some research on Workbench and found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480615/create-artisan-commands-for-package-laravel-5) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492394/laravel-5-creating-artisan-command-for-packages) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378460/laravel-5-package-development) on StackOverflow.

After a long time and some experimentation, I managed to get `laravel/workbench` into my composer.json, composer update, composer install, manually build a workbench.php config file, and finally use the PHP Artisan Workbench command to make a new package:

```
php artisan workbench Stevendesu/WorldDistance --resources
```

This created a directory: `/workbench/stevendesu/world-distance` with a number of sub-directories and only one file: `/workbench/stevendesu/world-distance/src/Stevendesu/WorldDistance/WorldDistanceServiceProvider.php`

This service provider class looked *essentially identical* to the file I created before, except that it was in the `/workbench` directory instead of the `/vendor` directory. I tried reloading the page and I still got the fatal error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 150:
Class 'Stevendesu\WorldDistance\WorldDistanceServiceProvider' not found
```

I also tried `php artisan vendor:publish`. I don't really know what this command does and the description wasn't helpful, so maybe it would help? It didn't.

## Question

How do I create a new service provider as a package so that in future projects I can simply include this package and have all the same functionality? Or rather, what did I do wrong so that the package I created isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After two days of playing with this I managed to find the solution. I had assumed that the directory structure mapped directly to the autoloader's path that it checked (e.g. attempting to access a class `Stevendesu\WorldDistance\WorldDistanceServiceProvider` would look in `vendor/stevendesu/world-distance/WorldDistanceServiceProvider`)... This isn't the case.

Reading through the composer source code to see how it **actually** loads the files, it builds a "classmap" - essentially a gigantic array mapping classes to their respective files. This file is built when you run `composer update` or `composer install` - and it will only be built correctly if composer knows the details of your package. That is - if your package is included in your project's composer.json file

I created a local git repository outside of my app then added my package to my app's composer.json file then ran `composer update` -- suddenly everything worked perfectly.

As for the:

> It didn't install as easily as it should have

the secret sauce here was **first** add the service provider to `/config/app.php` **then, second** run `php artisan vendor:publish`

Comment: You can use `composer dumpautoload` to update the classmap. `composer update` does a lot more than that. In case of Laravel it is sometimes necessary to run `php artisan clear-compiled`, too to clear Laravel's own optimized mapping metadata.